# Good environment for writing math examples

Tags: math-mode, examples

I am writing a mathematical report. where i need to include some examples, e.g., solving odes.  is there a package which provide a good environment for writing examples?

Comment: What in particular would you expect this package to do? `amsthm`, for example, will let you define a new "theorem-like" environment, i.e. it has a numbered heading ("Example 1.1") that can be referenced.

Comment: @Ulrich. Thanks Schwarz. Can you please post the latex-source. The document will contain lots of "examples" (e.g. solving a ode, solving a matrix equation). It is a very common thing. Is there a package to achieve it? Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possibility is to add `amsthm` package and then add something like:

```
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
```

for the definition of the Example environment. You can adjust the counters and such things as well.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\begin{document}
    Here is the first example:
    \begin{example}
        First example
    \end{example}
    and here's the second
    \begin{example}
        last example
    \end{example}
\end{document}
```