# New command or environment for numbered examples

Tags: macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good environment for writing math examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14881/good-environment-for-writing-math-examples)
>   [How to create a new counter for an a new environment that is in sync with subsections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33438/how-to-create-a-new-counter-for-an-a-new-environment-that-is-in-sync-with-subsec)

So I looked at the `\newcommand` command and I'm not quite sure how I can use that to my advantage. So I'm asking for your help :)

I am making a paper which has problems and examples in it. And I would like to have a command which will automatically make a mini text, let's say: `Example 1`, or `Example 1.1` (according to the sections and subsections), that is bolded and in a specific color.

Currently I have the following syntax:

```
{\bf \color{Green}Example 3.}\bigskip

Show this and that...

{\bf \color{Emerald}Solution:}\bigskip
```

And this looks fine in PDF, but it get's kinda tedious. I have to watch what is the example number, and have I accidentally repeated it and so on.

The same would be for exercises.

How can I do something like that, so that I only have to write (in code) `\example`

or just `\begin{example}`.

Comment: Have a look at [How to create a new counter for an a new environment that is in sync with subsections](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33438/how-to-create-a-new-counter-for-an-a-new-environment-that-is-in-sync-with-subsec) and [Good environment for writing math examples](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14881/good-environment-for-writing-math-examples).

Comment: I thing you should read `l2tabu`. `\bf` is obsolete.

Comment: e.g. `\newcommand{\example}[1]{\textcolor{Green}{\textbf{#1}}\bigskip}`, but defining a proper headline would be better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`amsthm` package](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amscls/amsthdoc.pdf) to make your own example environments.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtheoremstyle{own}%
    {3pt}% Space above
    {3pt}% Space below
    {}% Body font
    {}% Indent amount
    {\color{blue}\bfseries}% Theorem head font
    {:}% Punctuation after theorem head
    {\newline}% Space after theorem head
    {}% Theorem head spec

\theoremstyle{own}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]

\begin{document}
\section{Some Headline Text}
\begin{example}
Some Text.
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

---

Please note that `{\bf Text}` is old TeX syntax. With LaTeX you should use at least `{\bfseries Text}` or even better `\textbf{Text}`.

Comment: Good advice! However, sometimes it's better to point to already existing solutions on the site, if you might know one. Closing as a duplicate, thus giving a clearly visible link, is better than collecting duplicates on the site, though it doesn't give reputation.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz: Sorry, I didn’t think of that …

Comment: No problem, just a general remark. Your specific solution here is helpful, especially since it shows the way of customization regarding font and color.

Comment: This looks and works perfectly!! Thank you ^^